# Why is there a typecast in this macro body?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, memory-address

I study computer engineering, and the teachers here have always told us to define an µC address like this:

`#define FIO0DIR (* (unsigned int *) 0x2009C000) //GPIO direction register from the lpc1769`

But they never really explained why or what's happening.

So my question is: why is the cast there, at all?

Comment: This code is broken. Should be `volatile unsigned int*`, or better yet `volatile uint32_t*`. The `volatile` keyword is mandatory when declaring pointers to hardware registers.

Comment: No, you must have the volatile keyword or the compiler can and will eventually do weird optimizations. LPCXpresso uses gcc and gcc has very aggressive optimizations. Perhaps it works because you have optimizations disabled. Try `-O3` and watch the bugs pop up.

Comment: You're right, I never touched the optimization option and apparently it defaults to -O0. This is why everything has worked so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why the cast at all?

Because `0x2009C000` is an integer constant. Not an address. The C type system differentiates integers from addresses, even if the target architecture may not. It allows for conversions with various constraints on them, but the two types are *not* one and the same.

You need the cast to turn the integral constant into the proper pointer type, so you may dereference it and access what's at that address.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting `C11`, §6.5.3.2, *Address and indirection operators*

> The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type.

On it's own, `0x2009C000` is an **integer constant** (as mentioned in chapter §6.4.4.1), not a pointer type.

However, as we intent to use this integer constant as an *address*, and need to deference the address to get a value, there's the cast.

The cast tells the compiler to treat the integer constant value *as* a pointer to unsigned int, and then, the dereference operator acts on the *pointer* to get the value stored in that memory location.

Please note, do not consider this as a general applicability. Whether an integer constant value can represent a (valid) address location, is very much dependent on the platform and the environment.

Answer (score 0):

What you know is that your controller is mapped at address 0x2009C000, but to manipulate it you need to define the data type to store or read at that address. And this is what types are for in high level languages like C: specify what kind of data is stored at some address, its length (in bytes) and its representation (for example integer in 2's complement). So:

```
(unsigned int *)0x2009C000
```

means view constant 0x2009C000 as an address where an unsigned integer is stored.

```
* ((unsigned int *)0x2009C000)
```

means *the variable stored at address where an unsigned integer is stored*, simply the *unsigned integer variable stored at the given address*.